# Gridview JQuery plugin fires only once, custom confirm box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have checkbox in a gridview, when you click on the checkbox i need to show confirm message box.

i want to change the confirm message box button text from 'OK'/'cancel' to 'Yes'/No

For this i am using JQuery plugin http://www.invetek.nl/samples/confirmon/index.php

My gridView below

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">  
                        <ContentTemplate> 
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                style="text-align:center" CellPadding="3" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid"
                                BorderWidth="1px" ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="false" GridLines="Vertical" RowStyle-CssClass="GridRow" 
                                 OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"><%--OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"--%>
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F8F8F8" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_CarBrandID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CarBrandID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="Brand Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_CarBrandName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CarBrandName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="5%" HeaderText="Active" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:checkbox ID="lbl_Active" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkIsActive_CheckedChanged" Checked='<%# Eval("IsEnabled") %>'></asp:checkbox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="5%" HeaderText="Models" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button ID="img_Save" runat="server" OnClientClick="ShowModel()" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CarBrandID") %>' CommandName="ShowCarModels" Width="100%"  Text="Display Models"  />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </ContentTemplate>  
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

my JQuery for checkbox change

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('input[id*=lbl_Active]').confirmOn('change', function (e, confirmed)
            {
                if (confirmed)
                {
                    alert("1")
                    $(this).remove();
                }
                else
                { // Clicked no
                    alert("2");

                }
            });

        });

    </script>
```

I am getting the confirm box only once (first time) after page load, if i check uncheck again then the message box does not appear. i want for every click of checkbox i need the message box to show. please help me out.

Comment: If you're not getting any console errors, I would suggest that there is something wrong with your selector. Run it once, and then execute the selector in your browser's console and see whether you still have matching elements. I suspect that your page refreshes and you have no matching elements left.